friend function and headers inclusion loop
(Sorry for my bad english) I am coding two classes in c++, A and B, declared in two different header files.
I want to create class B a method (using operator overloading by the way) taking an A type variable in parameter. Plus I want this method to access the class A variable's fields, and to do so I have to declare it as a friend function of the A class.
`I tried this :
// B.h
#include "A.h"
class B {
    B& operator<<(A& var);
}

// A.h
#include "B.h"
class A {
    friend B& B::operator<<(A& var);
}`

But then my program doesn't compile. I guess the compiler doesn't like the inclusion loop but I don't know how to do otherwise.

Use forward decorations. class A; in B.h and class B; in A.h

Also, please use include guards. Easiest is to have #pragma once at top of all headers.

You cannot declare a B member function into A class. What you are looking for is how to forward-declare a friend class.
You may be interested to take a look at forward declarations if you're not already aware about that.
Now for your issue, you have to:

forward declare B as friend of A in A.h
forward declare A in B.h so that you can declare your function (operator<<()) which takes a reference to an A
Define the operator<<() in B.cpp

And that's it.

An example is better than 1000 words:
a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
   friend class B; // Forward-declare B as friend of A

   private:
      int m = 42;
};

#endif

b.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A; // Forward-declare A

class B
{
   public:
      int m = 0;

      B & operator<<(const A & a);
};

#endif

b.cpp
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

B & B::operator<<(const A & a)
{
   this->m += a.m;
   return *this;
}

test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
   A a;                      // a.m == 42 (which is private)
   B b;                      // b.m == 0 (which is public)
   std::cout << b.m << '\n';

   b << a;                   // b.m += a.m (since B is friend of A, it can access to a.m)
   std::cout << b.m << '\n';

   return 0;
}

